# php post not working as expected

Tags: php, html, email, sendmail

I have a form with 3 input fields , the below field is not working as expected , post data is not being posted , remaining two input fields are working correctly

```
<form id="main-contact-form" class="contact-form" name="contact-form" method="post" action="sendemail.php?m=std">

 <div class="row contact-wrap"> 
            <div class="status alert alert-success" style="display: none"></div>

            <form id="main-contact-form" class="contact-form" name="contact-form" method="post" action="sendemail.php?m=std">           
               <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Name *</label>
                        <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" required="required">
                    </div>
                     <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Email *</label>
                        <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" required="required">
                    </div>
                    </div>
               <div class="col-sm-5 col-sm-offset-1">
                <h4>Doing graduation</h4>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Name of college</label>
                        <input type="text" name="dngclgname" class="form-control" >
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Place </label>
                        <input type="text" name="dngclgplace" class="form-control">
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Completing in</label>
                        <input type="text" name="dngcomp" class="form-control">
                    </div>                        
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-5 col-sm-offset-1">
                <h4>Completed Graduation</h4>
                     <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Name of college</label>
                        <input type="text" name="clgname" class="form-control" >
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Place </label>
                        <input type="text" name="clgplace" class="form-control">
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Year of completion</label>
                        <input type="text" name="comp" class="form-control">
                    </div>                                  
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-5 col-sm-offset-1">
                <h4>Post Graduation</h4>
                     <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Name of college</label>
                        <input type="text" name="pgclgname" class="form-control" >
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Place </label>
                        <input type="text" name="pgclgplace" class="form-control">
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Year of completion</label>
                        <input type="text" name="pgcomp" class="form-control">
                    </div>                                  
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-5 col-sm-offset-1">
                 <h4>Working</h4>
                 <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Name of Company</label>
                        <input type="text" name="companyname" class="form-control" >
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Place </label>
                        <input type="text" name="companyplace" class="form-control">
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Working since</label>
                        <input type="text" name="companywrk" class="form-control">
                    </div> 
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Total no of years of experience</label>
                        <input type="text" name="companyexp" class="form-control">
                    </div> 
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Subject *</label>
                        <input type="text" name="subject" class="form-control" required="required">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Your Message/ Query/ Information required *</label>
                        <textarea name="message" id="message" required="required" class="form-control" rows="8"></textarea>
                    </div>                        
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" required="required">Submit Message</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form> 
        </div><!--/.row-->
```

this is a part of my php code

```
 header('Content-type: application/json');
$status = array(
    'type'=>'success',
    'message'=>'Thank you for contacting us. As early as possible  we will contact you '
);

// some code here (if condition, check if user has input other form , if user input this form everything is fine)

elseif($m == 'std'){
$name = trim(stripslashes($_POST['name']));     
$email = trim(stripslashes($_POST['email'])); 
$subject = trim(stripslashes($_POST['subject'])); 
$message = trim(stripslashes($_POST['message'])); 
$dngclgname = trim(stripslashes($_POST['dngclgname'])); 
$dngclgplace = trim(stripslashes($_POST['dngclgplace'])); 
$dngcomp = trim(stripslashes($_POST['dngcomp'])); 
$clgname = trim(stripslashes($_POST['clgname'])); 
$clgplace = trim(stripslashes($_POST['clgplace'])); 
$comp = trim(stripslashes($_POST['comp'])); 
$pgclgname = trim(stripslashes($_POST['pgclgname'])); 
$pgclgplace = trim(stripslashes($_POST['pgclgplace'])); 
$pgcomp = trim(stripslashes($_POST['pgcomp'])); 
$companyname = trim(stripslashes($_POST['companyname'])); 
$companyplace = trim(stripslashes($_POST['companyplace'])); 
$companywrk = trim(stripslashes($_POST['companywrk'])); 
$companyexp = trim(stripslashes($_POST['companyexp'])); 

$email_from = $email;
$email_to = 'my email address';//replace with your email

$body = 'Name: ' . $name . "\n\n" . 'Email: ' . $email . "\n\n" . 'graduating college name: ' . $dngclgname . "\n\n" . 'graduating college Place: ' . $dngclgplace . "\n\n" . 'graduation completion year: ' . $dngcomp . "\n\n" . ' graduated College name: ' . $clgname . "\n\n" . ' graduated College Place: ' . $clgplace . "\n\n" . ' Graduated Year: ' . $comp . "\n\n" . 'Post  Graduation College name: ' . $pgclgname . "\n\n" . 'Post Graduation College Place: ' . $pgclgplace . "\n\n" . 'Post Graduation Completion/completed year: ' . $pgcomp . "\n\n" . 'Company name: ' . $companyname . "\n\n" . ' Company place: ' . $companyplace . "\n\n" . 'Working since : ' . $companywrk . "\n\n" . 'Total no of years of experience : ' . $companyexp . "\n\n" . 'Subject: ' . $subject . "\n\n" . 'Message: ' . $message;

$success = @mail($email_to, $subject, $body, 'From: <'.$email_from.'>');
echo json_encode($status);
die;
}
```

When i click on submit am getting redirecting to the correct url and even mail is coming to my address but all the user input fiels are empty in the mail , even from address in the mail is also empty ,

Comment: You did not add the opening of the <form> tag, only the closing of the </form> tag.

Comment: it exist in the code, just code not formatted properly so not viewable in question.

Comment: Just to be sure the <form> tag's methods="post" right?

Comment: Yes there is form tag and yes method="post"

Comment: Try posting your $_POST variable and check.

Answer (score 0):

You should debug your code with var_dump($_POST).

You will see if all input value works.

When i've tried your code, everything worked well.